# How do I refresh a DIV content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div id='here'></div>
```

I am trying to refresh a certain div within a bunch of divs. The div content is basically generated by PHP along with data from a MySQL database in addition to many variables being sent with the help of an XMLHttpRequest.

The idea is to reload/refresh the div itself and not load a php file or to overwrite it with `.text` or `.html`. In this case, I cannot use `.load('file.php')`

What I have tried :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function updateDiv()
    { 
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = document.getElementById("here").innerHTML ;
    } 
</script>
```

and (for a every 3 second refresh) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#here').load('#here'));
    }, 3000);
});
```

Ideally, I would require something like :

```
function reloadDIV () {document.getElementById("here").innerHTML.reload}

function reloadDIV () {$('#here').load(self)}
```

so that I can use it in a onClick :

```
<a onclick='reloadDIV ();'>reload div</a>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid at the moment (extra closing `)`, but why is your URL not a real URL in the load?

Comment: Thats not how http requests work. If you want to recalculate stuff on the server, you need to make an http request. To load that content into a div without refreshing the page, you would need to make an ajax request. What do you mean by `"I cannot use .load('file.php')"`?

Comment: try `$(this).html("<Value>")` to update the inner html of div. To overwrite the html content, retain a copy html as display:none and copy content from that div to "here" div

Comment: Just replace that `self`with the URL of the script that provides the refreshed content.

Comment: You should use ajax to refresh DIV content depending new data returned from PHP script. Regarding your code, looks like you are misundertsand it. Why cannot you just use `$('#here').load('pathToPHP', dataOBJToPass or use string for GET mthod);`???  [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To reload a section of the page, you could use jquerys `load` with the current url and specify the fragment you need, which would be the same element that `load` is called on, in this case `#here`:

```
function updateDiv()
{ 
    $( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" );
}
```

- Don't disregard the space within the load element selector: `+ " #here"`

This function can be called within an interval, or attached to a click event

Comment: Wow. jQuery never ceases to impress me.

Comment: I've tested this and this is just what I needed. Thanks @Steve

Comment: This does reload particular div but it also creates div inside of div with same id. How to get rid of that div?
Before Refresh
`<div id="here">
</div>`

After Refresh
`<div id="here">
<div id="here"></div>
</div>`

Comment: I also need this but with the duplicate div removed. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: `function updateDiv()
{ 
    $( "#here" ).load(location.href + " #here" );
}` also worked for me without duplicating the div

Comment: jQuery is underrated.

Answer (score 25):

For div refreshing without creating div inside yours with same id, you should use this inside your function

```
$("#yourDiv").load(" #yourDiv > *");
```

Comment: Refresh in the sense of, data changes. Not re-rendering the div

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: This is super solution.

Answer (score 12):

Complete working code would look like this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
      $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here" );
}, 3000);
});
</script>

<div id="here">dynamic content ?</div>
```

self reloading div container refreshing every 3 sec.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following to just reload a `<div>` element:

```
$('#yourDiv').load('#yourDiv > *')
```

**Make sure to:** use an `id` and not a `class`. Also, remember to paste:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section of the HTML file, if you haven't already. In opposite case it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to achieve this using simple `$.get` method. `.html` work like innerHtml and replace the content of your div.

```
$.get("/YourUrl", {},
      function (returnedHtml) {
      $("#here").html(returnedHtml);
});
```

And call this using javascript `setInterval` method.

Comment: He is already using jQuery and $.get through `load` (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: the issue with 'load' is it will not allow you control/manipulate returned html.

Comment: If you dont need parameters, then dont put them `$.get("/YourUrl", function(returnedHtml){ ... });` is enought.