# Update Screen using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, screen

I am working with JavaScript and have made a cool program to chop up a photo and average the colors. I was adding a progress bar and whatever I did (have it in the loop that averages and have an set interval command) it would not update until the loop completed. I was wondering if anyone knew how to either force update the screen instead of calculating or a different way to solve this problem... thanks in advance.

```html
<html>
    
    <input id="input" type = "file" onchange="changeCanvas()" accept="image*/">
    <input type = "number" min="1" value="1" id="numb" onchange="calculate()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" value = "1">
    <input type="button" onclick= "calculate()" value ="Update">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mode" value = "1">
    <!input type="color" id="color" onchange= "addColor()">
    <br>
    <progress id="bar" value="0"> </progress>
    <br>
    <canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
    <br>
    <canvas id = "canvas2"></canvas>
    <script>
        var color = [[243,243,242],[161,165,162],[196,40,27],[13,105,171],[245,205,47],[27,42,52],[40,127,70],[75,151,74],[180,210,227]];
        var ratioHeightToWidth = 5/6;
        var pdone = 0;
        
        window.onload = function(){
            setInterval(progress,10);
        }
        
        function addColor(){
            var inColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
            var r = parseInt(inColor.substring(1,3), 16);
            var g = parseInt(inColor.substring(3,5), 16);
            var b = parseInt(inColor.substring(5,8), 16);

            //console.log(inColor + ", " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b)
            color[color.length] = [r,g,b];
        }
        
        function changeCanvas() {
            console.log("changeCanvas has started");
            var file = document.getElementById("input").files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                img.onload = function(){
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvasContext.drawImage(img,0,0);
                }
            } 
        }
        
        function calculate(){
            var checked = document.getElementById("check").checked;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var xa = document.getElementById("numb").value;
            var xw = (canvas.width/xa);
            if (checked){
                var ya = Math.ceil(canvas.height/Math.ceil(xw/ratioHeightToWidth));
                var yw = Math.ceil(xw*6/5);
            }else{
                var ya = Math.floor(canvas.height/Math.floor(xw/ratioHeightToWidth));
                var yw = Math.floor(xw/ratioHeightToWidth);
            }
            
            var space = 0;
            
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
            var canvas2Context = canvas2.getContext("2d");
            canvas2.width = xa*xw + space*xa;
            canvas2.height = canvas.height + space*ya;
            //canvas2Context.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
            
            for (var county = 0; county < ya; county++){
                for (var countx = 0; countx < xa; countx++){
                    var startx = countx*xw;
                    var starty = county*yw;
                    var endx = startx+xw;
                    
                    var rTot = 0;
                    var gTot = 0;
                    var bTot = 0;
                    var aTot = 0;
                    pdone = Math.floor(((countx+1)+county*xa)*100/(xa*ya));
                    console.log("Calculating: [" + countx + ", " + county + "], " + pdone + "% Compleated");
                    //progress(pdone);
                    
                    for (var countxp = startx; countxp < startx+xw; countxp++){
                        for (var countyp = starty; countyp < starty+yw; countyp++){
                            var colors = canvasContext.getImageData(countxp,countyp,1,1).data;
                            //console.log(colors);
                            rTot += colors[0];
                            gTot += colors[1];
                            bTot += colors[2];
                            aTot += colors[3];
                        }
                    }
                    var rAvg = rTot/(xw*yw);
                    var gAvg = gTot/(xw*yw);
                    var bAvg = bTot/(xw*yw);
                    var aAvg = aTot/(xw*yw);
                    
                    var rOut = 0;
                    var gOut = 0;
                    var bOut = 0;
                    
                    if (document.getElementById("mode").checked){
                        var value = 257;
                        for (var count = 0; count < color.length; count++){
                            var dR = Math.abs(rAvg-color[count][0]);
                            var dG = Math.abs(gAvg-color[count][1]);
                            var dB = Math.abs(bAvg-color[count][2]);
                            var avg = (dR+dG+dB)/3;
                            
                            if (avg<value){
                                rOut = color[count][0];
                                gOut = color[count][1];
                                bOut = color[count][2];
                                value = avg;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }else{
                        rOut = rAvg;
                        gOut = gAvg;
                        bOut = bAvg
                    }
                    canvas2Context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rOut + ", " + gOut + ", " + bOut + ")";
                    canvas2Context.fillRect(startx+space*countx,starty+space*county,xw,yw);
                }
            }
        }
        function progress(){
            //console.log("foo");
            document.getElementById("bar").value = pdone;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I also know that it is not any syntax problems or anything as it does update after the loop is done... I also have a console log saying the number that the progress bar should be and that appears in console but the screen doesn’t update

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! :). Can you please add your HTML as well as your JavaScript code to your question so we can help you? Thanks!

Comment: You could try this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the meta refresh tag...

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

this will refresh it every 30 seconds

Comment: The problem with that is it will refresh the whole website not just the screen, when refreshing the whole website it will remove all information that was uploaded or calculated