# How can I reload a function inside a function?

Tags: jquery, function, onchange

By click on `edit-item` I am loading a form via ajax:

```
 $('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.edit-item', function (e) {
    forms(e,this);  
  });
```

With this form my select field `#form_productgroup` is loaded. On change I would like to reload the form again.
My approach:

```
  $('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.edit-item', function (e) {
        forms(e,this);  
        $(document).on('change', '#form_productgroup', function(e) {
          forms(e,this);
       });
  });
```

But the form is not reloaded.

Comment: Did you try using `.load()`??

Comment: @Truextacy Do you mean like this `$('#form_productgroup').load(forms(e,this));`?

Comment: Yeah, similar to that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on( 'click', '.edit-item', function (e) {
        forms(e,this);  
  });

     $(document).on('change', '#form_productgroup', function(e) {
          forms(e,this);
       });
```

I think it's work!

EDIT:
IT's work because  `$(document).on(...)` is called when the component is loaded.