# Refreshing a single div

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have an automatically generating poem that previously used a page refresh to refresh the code. I'm trying to rewrite the code so that only the div refreshes, and it doesn't call a full page refresh. I'm trying the solution from this thread, but it's not working: [How do I refresh a DIV content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content/33801831).

Can anyone take a look at my code and help me figure out why it's not working?

```js
var adv_of_frequency = ['Sometimes', 'Often', 'Occasionally', 'Once in a blue moon', 'On a harvest moon', 'On the spring equinox', 'On the autumnal equinox']
var time_of_day = ['night', 'dawn', 'midday']
var preposition = ['under', 'past', 'for', 'away from']
var adjective = ['modest\n', 'scruffy\n', 'tiny\n', 'hairy\n', 'slimy\n', 'broken\n']
var noun = ['bicycle figurine', '3D print of a rambutan', 'depression booklet', 'anteater stuffed animal', 'hummingbird']
var place = ['on my nightstand,', 'in my dresser drawer,', 'between my sheets,', 'in the window planter box,', 'behind my bathroom mirror,']
var adjective2 = ['an enormous', 'an ancient', 'a greying', 'a mossy', 'a saggy', 'a drooling']
var noun2 = ['pebble.', 'owl.', 'potato.', 'kidney bean.', 'valerian root.', 'honeycomb.', 'yucca root.', ]

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here");
  }, 3000);
});

function randomizer(array_name) {
  array_name = array_name[Math.floor(Math.random() * array_name.length)];
  return array_name
}

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line1').innerText = randomizer(adv_of_frequency)
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line2').innerText = 'at ' + randomizer(time_of_day) + ','
}, 2000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line3').innerText = 'I look ' + randomizer(preposition) + ' the '
}, 3000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line4').innerText = randomizer(adjective) + randomizer(noun)
}, 4000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line5').innerText = randomizer(place)
}, 5000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line6').innerText = 'and find \n\ninstead'
}, 6000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line7').innerText = randomizer(adjective2)
}, 8500)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line8').innerText = randomizer(noun2)
}, 10000)

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line1').innerText = randomizer(adv_of_frequency)
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line2').innerText = 'at ' + randomizer(time_of_day) + ','
}, 2000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line3').innerText = 'I look ' + randomizer(preposition) + ' the '
}, 3000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line4').innerText = randomizer(adjective) + randomizer(noun)
}, 4000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line5').innerText = randomizer(place)
}, 5000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line6').innerText = 'and find \n\ninstead'
}, 6000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line7').innerText = randomizer(adjective2)
}, 8500)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('line8').innerText = randomizer(noun2)
}, 10000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='here'>
  <p id='line1'></p>
  <p id='line2'></p>
  <p id='line3'></p>
  <p id='line4'></p>
  <p id='line5'></p>
  <p id='line6'></p>
  <p id='line7'></p>
  <p id='line8'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please simplify the example a bit to the minimum required to show the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'd actually pasted it in there wrong, so I fixed that and omitted the section where I define variables. Should be clearer now hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume moving all you `generating` stuff into a separate function. Add some button/whatever to generate `refresh` event. And set you newly created function as event handler for that event. It may look like:

```js
var adv_of_frequency = ['Sometimes','Often','Occasionally','Once in a blue moon','On a harvest moon','On the spring equinox','On the autumnal equinox']
var time_of_day = ['night','dawn','midday']
var preposition = ['under', 'past','for','away from']
var adjective = ['modest\n','scruffy\n','tiny\n','hairy\n','slimy\n','broken\n']
var noun = ['bicycle figurine','3D print of a rambutan','depression booklet','anteater stuffed animal','hummingbird']
var place = ['on my nightstand,','in my dresser drawer,','between my sheets,','in the window planter box,','behind my bathroom mirror,']
var adjective2 = ['an enormous','an ancient','a greying','a mossy','a saggy','a drooling']
var noun2 = ['pebble.','owl.','potato.','kidney bean.','valerian root.','honeycomb.','yucca root.',]

var inProcess = false;

refresh(); 

document.getElementById('refresh').addEventListener('click', refresh)

function randomizer(array_name) {
    array_name = array_name[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_name.length)];
    return array_name
}

function clean() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#here p').forEach((p) => p.innerHTML = '')
}
  
function refresh() {
  if (inProcess) return;
  inProcess = true;
  setTimeout(function() { inProcess = false }, 10500);
  clean();
  setTimeout(function() {        
      document.getElementById('line1').innerText =  randomizer(adv_of_frequency)
  },1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line2').innerText =  'at ' + randomizer(time_of_day) + ','
  },2000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line3').innerText = 'I look ' + randomizer(preposition) + ' the '
  },3000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line4').innerText =  randomizer(adjective) + randomizer(noun)
  },4000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line5').innerText =  randomizer(place)
  },5000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line6').innerText = 'and find \n\ninstead'
  },6000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line7').innerText = randomizer(adjective2)
  },8500)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line8').innerText = randomizer(noun2)
  },10000)

  setTimeout(function() {        
      document.getElementById('line1').innerText =  randomizer(adv_of_frequency)
  },1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line2').innerText =  'at ' + randomizer(time_of_day) + ','
  },2000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line3').innerText = 'I look ' + randomizer(preposition) + ' the '
  },3000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line4').innerText =  randomizer(adjective) + randomizer(noun)
  },4000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line5').innerText =  randomizer(place)
  },5000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line6').innerText = 'and find \n\ninstead'
  },6000)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line7').innerText = randomizer(adjective2)
  },8500)
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('line8').innerText = randomizer(noun2)
  },10000)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> <meta> </meta> <p></p> <p></p> </head>
<body>

<button id='refresh'>refresh</button>

<div id='here'>
  <p id='line1'></p>
  <p id='line2'></p>
  <p id='line3'></p>
  <p id='line4'></p>
  <p id='line5'></p>
  <p id='line6'></p>
  <p id='line7'></p>
  <p id='line8'></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```