# JQuery how to refresh a div with button click

Tags: jquery

I would like to refresh a div element when clicking on a button. This question was asked before, but for some reason it does not work for me. Since I am new to programming, I am sure I'm missing something really obvious.

I found this already:[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content/33801831)

This is the code that I have now, based on the first answer of the above link. What I want, is that the time updates to the current time when I click on the button. But the time does not change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $("button").click(function(){
$("#test").load(" #test > *"); //as found on 
});
</script>

<script>
function updateDiv()
{ 
    $( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="updateDiv()">click me</button>

<p><div id="test">
<?php
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
</div>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see `#here` anywhere on your page,  so your click event seemingly will not do anything.

Comment: are you trying to load the contents of the div from a URL or simply put the current time in there?  It's a little jumbled exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I understand that I stated the question a bit strange. I would like to load the content of a div without reloading the whole page. This did not work for me. In order to get to understand my problem, I wanted to make a really simple div that was not static, so I used the time for that. So basically, a method to show the time does not help me. It really is about the general problem of updating a div after a button is sent (my real problem is: a user sends a message with a button, and then the number of credits of this person gets one less but this is only shown after a refresh now...) Sorry.

Comment: [I had not enough characters left in the comment] So in the 'real' problem my database is updated, and with in a certain part of the website php gets a variable from the database and inserts this to the HTML. I would like this to update after the button is pressed without the whole page reloading. I hope the question is more clear now. (will look at the other answers tomorrow, already way too tired now). Thanks everyone! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what exactly you are after, here is an example that just overwrites where the top `div` is pulled from a time website, and the bottom `div` just contains the current pc's time using `momentjs`.

```js
//wire up the click event to set the text of the div  (using momentjs for datetime cause its easy)
$("#refresh").on("click", 
  () => {
    //this one loads from a URL  (Tokyo Time)
    $("#refreshableURL").load("https://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i86ln45l/n248/tt0/tw0/tm1/tb4");
    //this one just loads some text in there.
    $("#refreshable").text(moment());
  }
);
//call the click event so it happens a first time.
$("#refresh").click();
```

```css
/* some simple styling */
div.time-display { 
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
<div id="refreshableURL" class="time-display"></div>
<div id="refreshable" class="time-display"></div>
```

### Edit

Added load from a URL into a seperate div

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this native method. No extra library need.

```js
function currentTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours() < 12 ? '0' + now.getHours() : now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes() < 12 ? '0' + now.getMinutes() : now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds() < 12 ? '0' + now.getSeconds() : now.getSeconds();
  var ampm = parseInt(hours) < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ampm;
}

document.querySelector('#test').innerText = currentTime();
document.querySelector('#refresh').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#test').innerText = currentTime();
});
```

```html
<button id="refresh">click me</button>
<p>The time is <span id="test"><?= date("h:i:sa"); ?></span></p>
```