# Have HTML table auto-refresh

Tags: json, page-refresh

I have a HTML table connected to a JSON file. I would like to have the table update every 15 seconds. I tried the following script, however, it causes the whole page to reload which can be inconvenient for people trying to view/access information.

Is there a way to have it only refresh the HTML table only and not the entire page?

```
    <script>
 setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 15000);
  </script>
```

**UPDATE**
I tried the following script, but it does not appear to make a difference.

```
<script> 
document.ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
        $( "#refresh" ).load(window.location.href + "#refresh" );
  }, 15000);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could make a request within your script

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    // your request here
  }, 15000);
</script>
```